# How to fix static tag is invalid error in setting a static file in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, static, django-staticfiles

I've followed the Django 3 documentation to set my static file on my web .And i did load static in my template , but it still keeps tell me that the static tag is invalid . im super confused and dont know wheres the problem? Have anyone face this kind of problem ?

Error like this

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 8: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Heres my directory structure

```
mblog/
|---maonsite/
|---mblog/
|---static/
    |---css
    |---js
    |---images
|---templates
    |---index.html
    |---product.html
```

And heres the setting.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '^)azutlc_vkzxpw4ghw@b$+q6g)5&%lsamt)s0i*k*gdvw##@b'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'maonsite',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
                    '/var/www/static/',]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . models import Post

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request): #index.html

    return render(request,'index.html')

def productpage(request):
    return render(request,'product.html')
```

and urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from maonsite.views import homepage,productpage

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',homepage), 
    path('product/',productpage),
]
```

Im appreciated for anyone who give me any piece of advice or solution
thx

Django: 3.0.7 Python: 3.8.3

Comment: Can you also post the template file? The one that is throwing the error while trying to load.

Comment: add `{% load static %}` at the beginning of your template where you use `{% static "..." %}`

Answer (score 0):

In your main `urls.py`, have you added static URLs?

```
# urls.py
from . import settings

urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

For this to work, your `settings.py` file should have these variables defined

```
# settings.py
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Finally, in your templates, make sure you have this line

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: Hi @黃楷修 if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.